# How to make expand-collapse different div heights according to device width using css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a div expand-collapse using Css/simple Javascript (no Jquery). I would like the div height which should be expanding-collapsing, different according to different device widths. In mobile, less text should be shown compared to full screen.

Code is working fine in smaller width. Unfortunately, I am facing problem with the working of code in full screen. When I am clicking on the "Show Less", the whole div collapses instead of showing.

I am new to Javascript. Please suggest.

Below is my code and my link for codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYbRyp

Html -

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sea mutat regione discere cu. Et vix aperiam `
`accusata deterruisset, no ius evertitur sententiae.<a style="text-   
 decoration: none;" id="displayText2" href="javascript:toggle();">See 
 More...</a><div class="more-mobile" id="foo2">  Ne movet ocurreret    
 salutatus vix, mnesarchum moderatius eos no. Graeci feugait expetenda ius 
 an. Ne veri referrentur efficiantur mea. Probatus definiebas cu ius, nec 
 aeque soluta hendrerit an.


 <a style="text-decoration: none;" id="displayText"  
 href="javascript:toggle();">See More...</a><div class="more-mobile"  
 id="foo"> 

 Duo id dignissim necessitatibus. Te ornatus accusamus mei, pri id soleat 
 euismod tractatos, eos laudem fabulas eu. Possim philosophia quo eu, 
 accumsan erroribus moderatius pri ex, in vel fuisset antiopam. Doctus 
 vocent ut quo, nam suscipiantur interpretaris ea, duo ea eruditi epicuri 
 apeirian.


An semper pertinacia vituperatoribus sea, mea ei natum oratio scaevola, at  
eum tation persius offendit. Quas deserunt his cu, cum eirmod regione eu, ut 
idque sadipscing has. Nulla iuvaret mel an. Mei eu dicunt assueverit.


</div>
</div>
```

Css -

```
 a#displayText2 {
 display: none;
 }
 div#foo {
display: none;
}
div#foo2 {
display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
a#displayText2 {
display: block !important;
}
a#displayText {
display: none;
}
div#foo {
display: block !important;
}
div#foo2 {
display: none;
}
```

Javascript -

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("foo");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "See More...";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "See Less";
  }
 } 
 //alert(window.screen.width);
 if (window.screen.width < 766) {

 function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("foo2");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText2");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "See More...";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "See Less";
 }
 } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make the div collapse-expand according to various heights in various width devices using java but could do the same using css and media queries. If anyone can do it in simple javascript (not jQuery), please post as an answer. Here below, I am giving the code for different height div expand-collapse using css -

Html -

```
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sea mutat regione discere cu. Et vix aperiam    
accusata deterruisset, no ius evertitur sententiae.</p>
<input class="toggle-box2" id="header2" type="checkbox" >
<label class="label1" for="header2"><span class="displayText2"></span>  
</label>
<div class="more-mobile" id="foo2"> <p> Ne movet ocurreret salutatus vix,  
 mnesarchum moderatius eos no. Graeci feugait expetenda ius an. Ne veri  
 referrentur efficiantur mea. Probatus definiebas cu ius, nec aeque soluta  
 hendrerit an.</p>

 <input class="toggle-box" id="header1" type="checkbox" >
 <label class="label1" for="header1"><span class="displayText"></span> 
 </label>

 <div class="more-one" id="foo">
 <p>Duo id dignissim necessitatibus. Te ornatus accusamus mei, pri id soleat   
 euismod tractatos, eos laudem fabulas eu. Possim philosophia quo eu,  
 accumsan erroribus moderatius pri ex, in vel fuisset antiopam. Doctus 
 vocent ut quo, nam suscipiantur interpretaris ea, duo ea eruditi epicuri  
 apeirian.</p>

 <p>An semper pertinacia vituperatoribus sea, mea ei natum oratio scaevola,   
 at eum tation persius offendit. Quas deserunt his cu, cum eirmod regione   
 eu, ut idque sadipscing has. Nulla iuvaret mel an. Mei eu dicunt 
 assueverit.</p>

 <label class="less" for="header1"><span style="float:right;"  
 class="displayText3">See Less</span></label>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

And this is the Css code -

```
  span.displayText2 {
  display: none;
  }

  span.displayText, span.displayText2, span.displayText3 {
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
  .toggle-box,.toggle-box2 {
   display: none;
   }

  .toggle-box ~ div#foo.more-one {
   display: none;
   }

   .toggle-box:checked ~ div#foo.more-one {
   display: block;
   }
   span.displayText:before, span.displayText2:before {

   content:"See More...";
   }
   .toggle-box:checked ~ .label1 span.displayText:before, .toggle-  
   box2:checked ~ .label1 span.displayText2:before {

   content:"See Less";
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 766px){ 
   span.displayText, span.displayText3 {
   display: none;
   }
   span.displayText2 {
   display: block !important;
   }
   span.displayText, span.displayText2 {
   margin-top: -5px;
   }
   .toggle-box2 ~ div#foo2.more-mobile {
   display:none;
   }

   .toggle-box2:checked ~ div#foo2.more-mobile {
   display:block;
   }
   .toggle-box ~ div#foo.more-one {
   display: block !important;
   }
   }
```

You can see the codepen here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKdZRE

Note - Please change the codepen view from horizontal to vertical to see the media query work and see that in vertical view, that is in lesser width device, only first para is displayed and rest hidden while in wider view device, the first two paras are displayed and rest are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your solution a little. Check out the JS Fiddles below. HTML for markup. CSS for style. JS for logic and DOM manipulation. Hopefully these fiddles help.

Hides some text at mobile 
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjrkzqhx/1/)

Makes text scrollable on fixed div at mobile
[js fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/h4csLvo9/)

```
var counter = 0,
    foo = document.getElementById( "foo" ),
    show = document.getElementById( "showText" );

show.addEventListener( "click" , function () {
   if ( counter%2 === 0 ) {
       foo.style.display = "block";
   } else {
       foo.style.display = "none";
   }
   counter++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. These code solutions you have given are working, but this is not what I require.

Say I have 7 paragraphs of text. In desktop, I would like to show first 2 paragraphs and hide the rest. In mobile, since space is less, I would like to show the first paragraph and hide the rest and which is shown on clicking the toggle.

Comment: My mistake! Check out this fiddle. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjrkzqhx/60/) Loops over children and hides based on click. Theres probably an easier solve with more css but this was how I did it. Only downside is you have to refresh screen to see change in amount of p's shown on click

Comment: Knew I was over thinking it. Here is a responsive solve that works with whatever current window width. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2LhLdmL/1/)

Comment: Please see the codepen how this is done in css. Please try to give similar solution in simple javascript (not jquery)

This is the codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKdZRE